# Fastest way to find the first key/value in a hash which is lower than the previous number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, optimization

So basically I have a hash which is filled of integers like this ->

```
{5=>1, 3=>2, 2=>3, 1=>4, 4=>5}
```

You will notice that the values are the position of the first number in the hash.

After I sort the hash based on the key, it looks like this ->

```
{1=>4, 2=>3, 3=>2, 4=>5, 5=>1}
```

What I want to do is remove from the original hash the first element whose value is lower then the previous one.

so the obvious way I can think to do this is:

```
lastvalue = -1
sortedNumbers.each{ |key,value|
   if value < lastvalue
      original_array.delete(key)
      return "deleted element"
   end

  last_value = value
}
```

Is this the best way to do this in terms of correctness/speed? Is this even a moderately good way of solving the problem in general?

Comment: I know that hashes have some sort of ordering in 1.9, but is it a good idea to rely on that ordering, rather than use an Array? (I'm not meaning to be sarcastic - I'm genuinely unsure)

Comment: Hashes are guaranteed to keep their insertion order in 1.9. In any case, it's easy to switch from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare successive values of an Enumerable, use `#each_cons`:

```
key = sortedNumbers.each_cons(2) do |(k1, v1), (k2, v2)|
  break k2 if v2 < v1
end
sortNumbers.delete(key)
```

Comment: would this be any faster then @davidb and my answer?

Comment: Not sure, might be slower too. I just prefer it, it's more general, there is no assumption that keys are (non-negative) integers, etc...

Comment: I'd be concerned about modifying the hash during iteration.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the greatest idea. Answer modified to avoid that. Could even be written into a 1-liner without a semicolon...

Answer (score 2):

I would write it this way:

```
lastvalue = -1
original_array.clone.each{ |key,value|
     original_array.delete(key); return "deleted element" if value < last_value
     last_value = value
}
```

Basicly the same stuff but a bit smarter code.